# "Cool water" vs. "cold water"

Tags: word-choice, nouns, adjectives, collocation

We often use "cool water". But can we use "cool water" or "cold water"? Which is correct? Examples:

> - I drink cool water only.
> - People always like cool water.

In the above examples, instead of the word *cool*, can we use *cold*?

Comment: 'Cool water' is water that's not hot, i.e., it could be at room temperature or cooler. 'Cold water' is water that is below room temperature or below comfort level. However, both 'cool drink' and 'cold drink' are used for the same beverage, though 'cool drink' is the alternative to 'hot drink' (hot beverage) and 'cold drink' is properly one that is chilled.

Comment: Do you just want general examples of how cool and cold are different?

Comment: What is unclear about this question? Why the close vote? What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 4):

**For Bodies of Water, choose "cool"**

When referencing a body of water like a swimming pool, pond, lake or even an ocean, use **"cool."** A **"cold"** body of water is dangerous and threatening. While a **"cool"** body of water is inviting and friendly; one might take a swim in a "**cool** lake," but not a "**cold** lake."

**For Drinks, choose "cold"**

In English (American, at least) you are more likely to see **"cold"** used in reference to drinks. If you search for "**cold** beverages" you'll find results like below. If you search for "**cool** beverages" you will have fewer results. (Google will actually return results for "cold beverages" because of its algorithms.)

The reason is that **"cold"** is considered *close to* ice; whereas **"cool"** is closer to **"mild"** or **"warm"** while still being cooler than either. If you are seeking refreshment, you are likely to want something **"cold"** instead of **"cool."**

**Sample Advertisements**

[image: Ice Cold Beer]

[image: Ice Cold Beer]

[image: Ice Cold Cocacola]

[image: Ice Cold Drinks]

Answer (score 1):

You can use **cold** in the following sentence in place of **cool**

> I drink cool water only.
>
> People always like cool water.

Whether it is correct or not depends on the meaning and the context, **cold** implies a lower temperature than **cool**, that is, **cold** is colder than **cool**. So it would most likely be preferable to swim in **cool** water than **cold** water

There is a short thread about this  [Cool versus Cold - when to use the adjectives...](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=405570)

An example taken from there points out that a"**cool** person" is quite different to a "**cold** person"

Answer (score 1):

English temperature terms are arrayed across the liquid range of water on a linear scale:

> •   *freezing   •   cold   •   cool   •   tepid/lukewarm   •   warm   •   hot   •   boiling* •

The polar words at the negative and positive ends (*freezing, boiling*) refer to state changes that limit the interest of human participants, who can't survive either freezing or boiling, personally.

Only such polar terms can take the intensifier *absolutely*:

- *It's absolutely freezing/boiling out there.*
- **It's absolutely cold/cool/tepid/lukewarm/warm/hot out there.*

Like all perceptual terms, these are relative to speaker, addressee, and context.
So there are no rules about "correctness".

Answer (score 0):

As 'warm' is to 'hot', 'cool' is to 'cold'.